# Spring parameter too long

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createItem", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Override
    public void createItem(@RequestParam(value="userId") String userId, @RequestParam(value="title") String title, @RequestParam(value="subtitle") String subtitle, @RequestParam(value="description") String description, @RequestParam(value="category") String category, @RequestParam(value="datapack") String datapack) {
        this.itemDAO.createItem(userId, title, subtitle, description, category, datapack);
}
```

I am creating RESTful application with Spring. The method above works just fine, but when the datapack is longer than a certain length it will result in error. The error says...

> Error parsing HTTP request header  Note: further occurrences of HTTP
>   header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

I need to pass the datapack as a parameter and the datapack itself will be a json file which I convert it to string.

The datapack file might be very complex and big. How do I solve this?

Here's the example of the request:

```
http://localhost:8090/createItem?userId=test&title=test&subtitle=test&description=test&category=test&datapack=
  {
    "CLASS": "com.mincom.ellipse.edoi.ejb.menu_item.MENU_ITEMRec",
    "INSTANCE": {
      "m_creationDate": "20150824",
      "m_creationTime": "001616",
      "m_creationUser": "SR4187",
      "m_lastModDate": "20150824",
      "m_lastModTime": "001616",
      "m_lastModUser": "SR4187",
      "m_menuType": "",
      "m_invokationString": "",
      "primaryKey": {
        "m_uuid": "3b4d95fe3dd3432fb00cde0cc25f903f"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "CLASS": "com.mincom.ellipse.edoi.ejb.i18n_descriptions.I18N_DESCRIPTIONSRec",
    "INSTANCE": {
      "m_creationDate": "20150824",
      "m_creationTime": "001616",
      "m_creationUser": "SR4187",
      "m_lastModDate": "20150824",
      "m_lastModTime": "001616",
      "m_lastModUser": "SR4187",
      "m_description": "CUSTOM_MENU",
      "primaryKey": {
        "m_locale": "en",
        "m_uuid": "3b4d95fe3dd3432fb00cde0cc25f903f"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "CLASS": "com.mincom.ellipse.edoi.ejb.top_level_menus.TOP_LEVEL_MENUSRec",
    "INSTANCE": {
      "m_creationDate": "20150824",
      "m_creationUser": "SR4187",
      "m_lastModDate": "20150824",
      "m_lastModTime": "001620",
      "m_creationTime": "001620",
      "m_lastModUser": "SR4187",
      "m_uuid": "3b4d95fe3dd3432fb00cde0cc25f903f",
      "primaryKey": {
        "m_name": "SX"
      }
    }
  }
```

Examples above works, but if I test with longer JSON file, it won't work.

Comment: what application server are you using? is it spring boot?

Comment: how do you form your http request? do you just submit a form or is it generated by javaScript somehow?

Comment: how big is this data you're transferring anyway? is it so big that it has to be split into multiple HTTP packages?

Comment: Yes, its spring boot. I form the request with angular. Even if i form the request directly from the browser, it still doesn't work

Comment: Do u know how to split the packages?

Comment: Why are you not using POJO which can be mapped to JSON object?

Comment: you don't need to do the split manually. It's done by your OS, but you must modify the http header manually if it happens

Comment: Can you try with `RequestBody` and `ResponseBody`?

Comment: yeah. If you're sending the stuff as JSON instead of normal HTTP parameters, then you should go for the solution with @RequestBody

Comment: @KamilMilkaJanowski Don't we need to create model class if we use @RequestBody? because I can't create model for the datapack, as it is uncertain.

Comment: yeah, you do. But you're sending the JSON data, so you don't really have any choice

Comment: I send the JSON file as a string, and I store it as a string as well. So, is there a way to send the parameter as a very long string? I tried the request from angular like you showed me, but it does not work. @KamilMilkaJanowski

Answer (score 1):

Create a controller method that shall be receiving the JSON data posted by $http service using XHR (AJAX)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savecompany_json", method = RequestMethod.POST)   
public  @ResponseBody String saveCompany_JSON( @RequestBody Company company )   {       
    //
    // Code processing the input parameters
    //  
    return "JSON: The company name: " + company.getName() + ", Employees count: " + company.getEmployees() + ", Headoffice: " + company.getHeadoffice();
}
```

Create a POJO which maps to JSON object

```
public class Company {

    private String name;
    private long employees;
    private String headoffice;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Long getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }
    public void setEmployees(Long employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
    public String getHeadoffice() {
        return headoffice;
    }
    public void setHeadoffice(String headoffice) {
        this.headoffice = headoffice;
    }
}
```

[Source](http://vitalflux.com/angularjs-post-json-data-using-ajax-springmvc/)

Answer (score 0):

If the request is really big (like when sending files for instance), you might want to change your content-type in your http header. For instance (although might look differently depending on what you're actually sending):

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: url,
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   },
   data: {
      data: model,
      file: file
   }
});
```

Then if the request is too big for the server to accept it, you might need to extend the request size limit. If you're using spring boot, you may go to your application.properties file (should be located under src/main/resources, but if it doesn't exist yet, create it manually) and add the following properties:

```
multipart.maxFileSize=3MB
multipart.maxRequestSize=3180KB
```

Comment: Is that the request from angular?

Comment: yeah, this is how you do the requests in angular

Answer (score 0):

You are using a POST request anyhow, so simply send the parameters in the body with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded like a normal form submission instead of in the URL.